# idea/solution how to edit PBL (PowerBuilder Library) files?

Tags: python, .net, powerbuilder

I want to get the content of DataWindow from PBL (PowerBuilder Library) file and edit it in place. The idea is to read the pbl file, and access individual DataWindows to modify source code. Somehow, I have managed to do the first part with PblReader .NET library using IronPython. It allows me to read PBL files, and access DataWindow source code. However it doesn't support modifications. I would like to know if anyone have an idea for editing PBL files?

Comment: So you want to use Python to edit them instead of PowerBuilder? A Classic PB pbl contains the source code and a compiled version of the code. Even if you could modify the source code, you'd probably still need PowerBuilder to compile it. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Well its ok to compile it again in PB if necessary.The idea is that trough python script I can replace for example font type in all datawindows, instead of going one by one and replace in PB.

Comment: Editing and compiling are tightly bound concepts with PowerBuilder and PBLs; you can't separate them. What's the objective? There may be a way to do something like this, but it's incredibly convoluted and difficult (and unless you've got weeks to put into this process, requires a third party commercial tool). If you just don't like the PB IDE, I can almost promise you that you'll hate figuring out how to compile from raw text source files worse.

Comment: The way I make that sort of change is to check the objects out of our source management system using the SCM tool. This gives me the export files. I do whatever changes I want, then go to PB and refresh the status which then shows them checked out to me. Then I can import, test and check in from PB. I use Notepad++ to do global replace in multiple files. I've been known to run `sed` on entire source trees before Terry released PBL Peeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PowerBuilder application can load a DataWindow from a PBL (doesn't have to be in the library path), modify it, and save it back to the PBL. I've written a couple of tools that do that. PowerBuilder will allow you to modify the DataWindow according to its object model using the `modify` method. I don't know why anyone would want to reinvent all of this. I recall seeing Python bindings for PB somewhere. You could get the DW syntax from PB, call out to Python, then save it back in PB. But you'd have to do all the parsing in Python, whereas PB already understands the DW. Finally I'm surprised Terry didn't plug PBL Peeper. You could use PBL Peeper to export the DataWindows, massage them to your hearts's content in Python. then import them back into PB.

Comment: Wow, this PBL Peeper is a tool I was really looking for, thanks!

Comment: Apparently I'm still fuzzy on the objective. Maybe too much egg nog? I guess I fixated on "edit in place". If you're willing to use PB, ORCAScript or some other PB-linked tool to write back to the PBL (and PBL Peeper has had this part removed/disabled, so I'm even more confused about the enthusiasm now), then it's all good. Note that for the power-user, this type of activity can be done at run time, using the Create() or LibraryImport() PowerScript functions to leverage the changed DW code.

Comment: PowerBuilder 'supports' an external tool getting source, modifying it, and putting the modified code back in via the ORCA library. For most purposes, you're better off exporting the objects, modifying them, and reimporting them. That's what Terry originally made PBL Peeper for. It also used to import the objects back, before we learned that was a Bad Idea(TM). I recommend you go through the documentation, because there are all sorts of non-obvious things that PP can do. Also maybe Terry will offer the link to 4.1.1 which is slightly more beta than regular PP and has more good stuff.