# Is there any way to apply a project-wide regex replacement in Powerbuilder?

Tags: regex, powerbuilder

I would like to do a mass replacement in a Powerbuilder project. *(For the story, I'd like to replace most ".object." by SetItem/GetItem equivalents, for diverse reasons)*

While it won't be covering necessarily all cases, I would like to know if there is a way to apply a regex find/replace over an entire workspace, or at least over selected pbl files.

I have seen this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920682/idea-solution-how-to-edit-pbl-powerbuilder-library-files), but I'm wondering if there is a more simple way than exporting everything (especially that reimporting doesn't seem like the funniest thing to do).

Comment: Not that I don't like the idea (.object. leaves objects in memory for garbage collection... bad for long running loops), don't forget that .object. can be used for more than just data assignment. I'd hate to see you replace a block data replacement with a single SetItem() and break your app. (I'd like to think there's a regex way to only catch single data assignments...)

Comment: @Terry I have thousands of [] assignments, which are quite easy to restrict to in regex. Now that doesn't solve all cases, but it would save a lot of busywork already. And besides, that's exactly the idea behind the replacement. We are switching to 64bits for volume reasons, and the countless .object. are tripping up the memory cap, so we try to make a full sweep

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to export and make a small application indicating rules make the change in the exported file, then import.

Comment: It's unfortunate that there is no better way, pity

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Especially since the getitem methods vary by datatype.  There are a variety of global replace type utilities  (like PibblePeeper) which could help but you would have to do many passes through the code.

Comment: Most of all, Pbl Peeper doesn't seem to handle regex

Comment: @Gnoupi - Yup, PP doesn't handle regex, nor does the search & replace handle imports any more (that's left to the user... too long a story for comments). I tried to stick mostly with native PB functionality, and Match() just doesn't cut it for S&R. You could probably use PP for searching your code for instances (easy to restrict your searches to just scripts), then export Find results and regex-search for cases related to my paranoid comment to the original question.

Comment: @Terry I gathered indeed that importing was a Bad Idea, from some other comments, hence deactivating it in PP. Comments are too short for this, but out of curiosity, would you have a link to a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Short version: Sybase has warned that the PB compiler isn't re-entrant and that calling the compiler from PB is a **Bad Idea** (TM). You could use PBOrca to pull it all back in. I think that warning is in the ORCA documentation.

Comment: What Hugh says is true, but I did have it working using ORCA. The kicker: you had to be on the same EXACT version that I compiled with, down to the build or it  would crash (DLL compatibility), so I had to pump out PP versions (and keep them available) for every public patch. Confusing for users. Pain for me. Plus, Sybase's import wasn't as competent as PowerGen's. Deprecated feature.

Comment: @Terry, yeah, I can understand why it went this way indeed. Thanks for the details.